# Delphi 7 opendialog has garbage in filename when used in Windows 10

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

This is my first post here so please forgive me if I am not doing it right.

I am using Delphi 7 on my Windows 10 machine. When I use the TOpenDialog I get garbage in the filename property on close. This is what I get back þƒ‡uÔÁ™ßðæRw. I created a simple form with a button and a edit box to show the problem here. Could someone please assist me.

The code is below.

```pascal
    procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    begin
      opendialog1.Execute();
    end;

    procedure TForm1.OpenDialog1Close(Sender: TObject);
    begin
      edit1.Text := opendialog1.FileName;
    end;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't use the `OnClose` event of the dialog. That is invoked after the underlying dialog object, which owns the file name data, has been destroyed.

Instead respond to the dialog when `Execute` returns.

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin 
  if opendialog1.Execute() then
    edit1.Text := opendialog1.FileName;
end;
```

Note that you must also test the return value of `Execute` to handle the user cancelling the dialog.

Comment: To avoid any possible misunderstanding: it is fine to access file name after the dialog closes, which is the case when `Execute` returns. The VCL class hands the cached file name here. But the `OnClose` handler has an unfortunate timing where the api dialog has a valid handle but doesn't respond to requests (it's processing `WM_DESTROY`). Since the handle is valid, VCL asks the dialog the file name here.

Comment: I have changed my code and approach accordingly and it is working fine. Thank you.